# How to get data preferentially from the joined tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server. I have three tables, `TableA`, `TableB` and `TableMain`, with `Date`, `StartTime` and `FinishTime` columns.

I have to write a SQL statement which has to pull these three column values from `TableMain`. If the same date is present in the `TableA`, then the `StartTime` value should come from it, otherwise just use the value from `TableMain`. Similarly, if a `FinishTime` is present in the `TableB`, then in the final output that value should replace the one in `TableMain`.

I would like to do it by joining these three tables. The following shows the data in these three tables and the final expected query output.

**TableA**:

```
Date        StartTime
10/14/2016  11:00 AM
10/16/2016  10:00 AM
10/18/2016  11:30 AM
```

**TableB**:

```
Date        FinishTime
10/15/2016  3:00 PM
10/16/2016  4:00 PM
10/17/2016  6:30 PM
10/18/2016  5:00 PM
```

**TableMain**:

```
Date        StartTime   FinishTime
10/14/2016  8:00 AM     10:00 PM
10/15/2016  8:00 AM     10:00 PM
10/16/2016  8:00 AM     10:00 PM
10/17/2016  8:00 AM     10:00 PM
10/18/2016  8:00 AM     10:00 PM
```

Desired output:

```
10/14/2016  11:00 AM    10:00 PM
10/15/2016  8:00 AM     3:00 PM
10/16/2016  10:00 AM    4:00 PM
10/17/2016  8:00 AM     6:30 PM
10/18/2016  11:30 AM    5:00 PM
```

Comment: All you need is some left joins and a derived table result.  See my answer below.

Comment: If there is anyone who updates and edits questions in the sql tag the best it is marc_s thanks @marc_s

Comment: @JonH: aw, thanks so much, Jon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truly untested but something like this:

```
SELECT
   t.DateVal,
   t.Start,
   t.Finish
FROM
(
SELECT
   tm.DateVal AS DateVal,
   CASE WHEN a.Start IS NOT NULL THEN a.Start ELSE tm.Start END AS Start,
   CASE WHEN b.Finish IS NOT NULL THEN b.Finish ELSE tm.Finish END AS Finish
FROM 
   TableMain tm
LEFT JOIN
   TableA a
ON
   a.DateVal = tm.DateVal
LEFT JOIN
   TableB b
ON
   b.DateVal = tm.DateVal
) t
```

The key here is that you use some left joins, a case statement, and a derived table result (in this case `t`).  Please note my column names, simply change to what your column names are and this should work.

Answer (score 2):

COALESCE would work here as well, without all the CASE statements:

```
SELECT tablemain.date,
COALESCE(tablea.starttime, tablemain.starttime),
COALESCE (tableb.finishtime, tablemain.finishtime)
FROM tablemain
LEFT JOIN tablea
ON tablemain.date = tablea.date
LEFT JOIN tableb
ON tablemain.date = tableb.date
```

COALESCE takes the first non NULL value in the series. So if there is a start date in table a, it will take that. If not, it will take the start date from table main. The same logic holds for finish date and table b